# Kendo UI/Mobile - Get JSONP and append to listview

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm just starting out with Kendo mobile (impressed so far - coming from JQM). I'm trying to pass a postcode to a url which returns some json (houses near that area) and then append it to a listview using Datasource. However, it fails an in console I just get:

```
Error [object Object]
```

Heres my code: ** Updated **

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, 
{
    transition:'slide'
});

function onBodyLoad() {
    //document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    // Use the following for testing in the browser
    getProperties(onResult);
}


function getProperties(callback) {

    var template = kendo.template($("#propertiesListViewTemplate").html());

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {

                url: 'http://www.someurl.me/getproperties.php?postcode=hx59ay',
                dataType: "jsonp"
            }
        },

        schema: {
            data: "listing" //??? Not sure what this should be???
        },


        error: function(e) {
            console.log("Error " + e);
        },
        change: function() {
            $("#propertyResultListView").html(kendo.render(template, this.view()));
            console.log(this.view());
        }
    });
    dataSource.read();
    $("#propertyResultListView").kendoMobileListView({dataSource:dataSource,template: $("#propertiesListViewTemplate").html()});

}

function onResult(resultData) {
    console.log("Results " + listing);
    $("#propertyResultListView").kendoMobileListView({dataSource: kendo.data.DataSource.create({data:resultData}),
        template: $("#propertiesListViewTemplate").html()});
}
```

I'm sure this is down to the schema part of the Datasource but I'm lost as to what it should be (the docs havent really helped).

The JSON thats returned is:

```
{"country":"England","result_count":510,"longitude":-1.826866,"area_name":"Caldercroft, Elland HX5","listing":[{"image_caption":"Main Image","status":"for_sale","num_floors":"0","listing_status":"sale","num_bedrooms":"2","agent_name":"Daniel & Hirst","latitude":53.688934,"agent_address":"110 Commercial Street","num_recepts":"0","property_type":"Detached","country":"England","longitude":-1.843375,"first_published_date":"2012-10-11 19:05:42","displayable_address":"Elland HX5","street_name":"EXLEY LANE","num_bathrooms":"0","thumbnail_url":"http://images.zoopla.co.uk/f7f6791d95dadef11b340be2949bd8957079168f_80_60.jpg","description":"Comments","post_town":"Elland","details_url":"http://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/26491359","agent_logo":"http://static.zoopla.co.uk/zoopla_static_agent_logo_(120721).png","price_change":[{"date":"2012-10-11 16:45:02","price":"37500"}],"short_description":"We are pleased to offer ...","agent_phone":"01484 954009","outcode":"HX5","image_url":"http://images.zoopla.co.uk/f7f6791d95dadef11b340be2949bd8957079168f_354_255.jpg","last_published_date":"2012-11-21 17:31:46","county":"West Yorkshire","price":"37500","listing_id":"26491359"}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? The whole datasource schema is confusing to me. If it helps to describe what I'm trying to do in JQM I'd do something like

```
   $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getproperties.php?postcode=' + postcode + '&minimum_beds=' + minimumBeds + '&minimum_price=' + minimumPrice + '&maximum_price=' + maximumPrice , function(data) {

    $('#propertyList li').remove();

    // Loop through json data and append to table
    listings = data.listing;
    $.each(listings, function(index, property) {

        console.log(property.image_url);
        console.log(property.price);

        $('#propertyList').append('<li><a href="propertydetails.html?id=' + property.listing_id + '">' +
                '<img src="' + property.thumbnail_url + '"/>' +
                '<h6>' + property.property_type + '</h6>' +
                '<p>' + property.displayable_address + '</p>' +
                '<p><strong>&pound;' + property.price + '</strong></p>');

        $('#propertyList').listview('refresh');
    });

});
```

Template

```
<!-- Template for Property results, need to change below fields -->
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="propertiesListViewTemplate">
    <h4>${property_type}</h4>
    <p>${street_name}</p>
</script>
```

*** Update - Code updated for Pechka answer ****

I have now changed my service to return jsonp (with a callback) as per the link you mentioned. I can now see the jsonp in developer tool network tab -

jQuery17106739131917711347_1354193012656({"country":"England","result_count":179,"longitude":-1.83261282209016,"area_name":"Elland","listing":[{"image_caption":"","rental_prices":{"per_week":75,"accurate":"per_month","per_month":"325"},"status":"to_rent","num_floors":"0","listing_status":"rent","num_bedrooms":"1","agent_name":"Boococks","latitude":53.68668 ...

Nothing is getting populated into my template though, so no list view is created (I realize this is probably down to my newness to kendo). Can you see where I'm going wrong, this seems incredably tricky compared to JQM... Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Why dataType jsonp when your service returns json?

Comment: @Pechka because of cross domain ajax. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Then your service should return a jsonp result. Check this out http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

Comment: As you can see there is a special callback function which is invoked (it is not just a regular json as you would expect :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm just trying to simplify this thing to see where the error happens.
So you define your DataSource with a parameterMap and a Model:

```
var dataModel = new kendo.data.Model.define({
    id: 'listing_id' //specifies a unique key, every other key is mapped automatically
});
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        parameterMap:function (_data, _operation) {
            if (_operation == 'read') {
                return {
                    postcode: 'bd11db' //sending parameters via parameterMap
                };

            }
        },
        read: {
            url: 'http://www.someurl.me/getproperties.php',
            dataType: "jsonp"
        }
    },

    schema: {
        //data: "ResultSet.Result" //data specifies which "node" to use for the actually returned data, since you want the complete object you dont need to specify this
        model: dataModel //using the specified model
    },


    error: function(e) {
        console.log("Error " + e);
    },
    change: function() {
        $("#propertyResultListView").html(kendo.render(template, this.view()));
        console.log(this.view());
    }
});
dataSource.read();
```

Sorry I dont really see through all these callbacks at first glance, but this datasource should at least return (or log) the JSON you get from the server

Might not solve your problem completely, but may be a hint in the right direction ;) Feel free to comment on things that are unclear or (hopefully not) wrong

Good Luck :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I've used your code and the error has gone but im not getting anything logged in console or getting added to the list view?? Any ideas, should i post more code? thanks in advance

Comment: the change event is fired when the DS is ready (has data available) if the console.log isnt there it either means the DS is never ready or has no data. Try logging something unrelated like 'DS firing change event' If this isnt fired either, somethings wrong with the DS

Comment: I just saw that the street_name is nested in `listing` so you might go right with calling `${listing.street_name}` or defining `'listing'` as the `data` attribute in the schema as you previously did. I dont know if you can/must specify `listing.listing_id` in the model

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to configure your service to return [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (jsonwithpadding).

You can see the dataSource bound to a jsonp in action in [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/listview/pull-with-endless.html) demo. Use the network tab of the browsers developer tools and see the difference in the format.

Comment: Hi, I've tasken your advice and updated my service to produce jsonp (with a callback as per the article you linked to). I'm still not getting any luck though, but I appear to have jsonp returned to my dev tools network tab - could you take a look at my updated code above please? Thanks for all your help, getting very frusted with Kendo so far, hopefully you'll get me back on track! Thanks

Comment: Not sure what else might be wrong. Are there any JavaScript errors in the console? And if there are whats the problematic line?

Comment: Theres no errors, and nothing in console. In the network tab in chrome dev tools, I can see the response which looks like json but nested in a callback but the list view doesnt get created and nothing gets added to the screen. If I console.log(this.view()); under the datasource change method I get some odd looking (possibly kendo) js in console with my results from the web service nested in it - I just cant get it to create the nest view...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Wrap your jsonp reply in a var like "results" so that it looks like this:

```
jQuery1820051476528169587255_1366217103715({"results":[{"id":"3","entry_stamp":"November 30, -0001 12:00 am","comments":null}]})
```

Designate the wrapper var:

```
schema: {
        data: "results" //the portion of your jsonp that you want
    }
```

Call the template:

```
$("#propertyResultListView").kendoMobileListView({
   dataSource:dataSource,
   template: $("#propertiesListViewTemplate").html()});
```

You shouldnt need to call dataSource.read(); as the call to the template will do this autoMagically. Try this below as a completed code view (i removed some other items that may cause issues - you will need to replace them once you get this simple version working:

```
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: 'http://www.someurl.me/getproperties.php?postcode=hx59ay',
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "results" //your reply data
            }

        });

        $("#propertyResultListView").kendoMobileListView({
            dataSource:dataSource,
            template: $("#propertiesListViewTemplate").html()

        });
```